# Possible wrong inequality.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(A,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f$ a measurable real
function. Define $\text{ess} \sup (f)=\inf\{c\in \mathbb{R}:\mu(\mid f\mid>c)=0\}$ and $\text{ess} \inf (f)=\sup\{c\in \mathbb{R}:\mu(\mid f\mid<c)=0\}$.

Show that ess $\inf(f)\leq \int_A f d\mu \leq \text{ess} \ \sup(f)$ for all measure on $\mathcal{F}$ and measurable $f$.

But I was thinking that if I take the Lebesgue measure space and $f=1$, then the integral is infinite but ess $sup (f)$=ess $inf (f)=1$. What do you think? Is this counterexample valid?

Comment: This holds only true for probability measures.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven My counterexample is valid? The Lebesgue integral of constant function on real is infinity but the essential sup and inf is 1

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Yes it is. In fact, you can take the constant $1$ function and it either violates the upper or the lower bound if the measure is not equal to 1.

Comment: this only holds for finite measure spaces, as probability spaces